# Getting validation error on checkout billing tab for custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, form-validation

I have added two custom attribute named as country_code and mobile. And added those fields in 
        `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml`

And the fields are reflecting on register page and working good. Please note that I haven't added these fields in
    `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml`

But when I try to complete my checkout I got an alert box saying that

> "Country Code" is a required value., "Mobile Number" is a required
>   value.

So I added those field in `billing.phtml` just to check the behavior. But this time I also got the same alert box. Refer below screens.

[image]

[image]

Hope I explained clearly. Suggest what goes wrong here.

Comment: Did you check the attribute declaration, if it's mentioned as required field or not.

Comment: @RahulKumarDas I made it required. Refer my second screen, I entered the values. I highlighted in red box. Still it is showing the validation

Comment: Do you get any console errors?