# How to delete custom customer attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute, delete

I added some attribute for customer entity. This causes some error on checkout page. That I described in other question.

[Getting validation error on checkout billing tab for custom attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69979/getting-validation-error-on-chekout-billing-tab-for-custom-attribute)

How can I make those attributes as not required field or delete those attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the database directly as there is no GUI for customer attributes. Remember to back-up your database before running this.

```
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code LIKE 'yourattributecodehere';
```

Or if you just want to make it optional (not required):

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code LIKE 'yourattributecodehere';
```

Also you might have a table prefix, so in this case, it would be `yourprefix_eav_attribute`

Comment: Just to be safe, always run a select with the same where clause before deleting something, this way you can check the affected rows before deleting. And if you want to go extra safe after running the select take note of the id and delete using id instead than attribute code